# Use mouse cursor as image on a website

Tags: css, html

I wonder if its possible to use the browsers cursor as an image.

So for example that I could use somewhere on the page the resize image of the cursor.

I tried to find some answer to this, all I could find is how to use an image as a cursor.

And interesting enough, 
Microsoft uses images to show the cursors:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa358795.aspx

Mozilla also uses images:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor

Which makes sense, since one might have complete different set of cursors (maybe even a broken set - not having all variants) defined in the Operating System. And so it wouldn't show what they actually wanted to show. So my hopes are still up that there is some way.

---

I suppose what I want is not possible, but I thought lets ask.
Maybe its very simple and I am really overlooking something I hope.

Comment: are you looking for something like this -  `cursor:url("path_to_image"), auto;`. I guess not , just clarifying.

Comment: The mozilla link is valid for every browser …

Comment: Im more looking for something like, background-image: cursor('resize');
Kinda the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simply not possible to use the image which is used by the browser.